# Ending session when Logging out in JSP

Tags: jsp, session

Following is my navigation bar for include the logout button for the page.

I want to end the session when a user click the logout button.

I found sample codes by googling and added for my code but following code shows an error.(Check the error in screenshot)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hi, <%=session.getValue("Username") %><b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li align="center" class="well">

            <a href="index.jsp" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
            <%
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            %>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Help me to correct this code..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a session is created for you by container if the session is not available. For JSP use to avoid create new session:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Before accessing the `session` variables check for the `session` if available not. Without session, if we call the `session object` methods it will raise `IlleagalStateExcetion`.

```
   <% if (session!=null) {%>
     <%=session.getValue("Username") %><b class="caret"></b></a>
   <% } %>
```

The session is getting invalidated every time the page loads, by not clicking on the `Logout`. So by clicking on the `Logout` put a separate page to `invalidate the session`.

Here I ma using it as `logout.jsp`, it contains the session invalidation code:

```
 <!-- For not creating new session -->
 <%@ page session="false" %>

 <body>
     <%
     // for checking the session is available or not, if not available it will throw exception, "Session already invalidated."
      if (sesssion!=null) {
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
      }
     %>
 </body>
```

And Finally change the `Logout` link like the following:

```
<a href="logout.jsp" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
```

Give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your session is already killed before you click the logout link. Also in jsp pages session are auto-created. You need to take care of that while accessing any attribute from the `session`. Do follow the steps suggested by `Srinu`.